# Sending http post request consuming soap service using cfx-client in mule

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, mule, esb

Is it applicaple in cfx-client mule  to send http post request with input paramaters in the body .

That's which I need below .

**Request :**

http://localhost:8088/test/integrate

with paramaters in request body like  token and guid

**Response :**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:gen="http://www.test.com/generic-operation-message">

   <soapenv:Body>
      <gen:Dummy>
      <gen:Result>
             <gen:ErrorCode>0</gen:ErrorCode>
             <gen:ErrorDesc>success</gen:ErrorDesc>
             <gen:Severity>info</gen:Severity>
          </gen:Result>
      </gen:Dummy>
      </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```